# std::vector pointer - expression must have class type error

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to create an iterator based on a function I'm calling to return a pointer to a vector in an instantiated object but I'm met with an error that the `expression must have class type`. What is this error referring to?

```
std::vector<GUIItem*> *childitems = dynamic_cast<GUIWindow*>(it_guilist)->GetChildItems();
std::vector<GUIItem*>::iterator it_childitems = childitems.begin();
```

The error occurs on childitems.begin().

My GetChildItems function is as follows:

```
std::vector<GUIItem*>* GUIItem::GetChildItems()
{
    std::vector<GUIItem*> * childitems = &m_childitems;
    return childitems;
}
```

I should mention that GUIWindow is a class derived from the GUIItem base class. Any ideas?

Comment: Please write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without it it is very hard to reproduce your error and you are unlikely to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`childitems` is a pointer, not an object. Use `childitems->begin()`.

Comment: Doh! Should have seen that one. So simple. Thanks for 'pointing' it it out (heh, maybe I should change career track and write a book of puns).

Comment: @Jamie4840 You absolutely should not, there just isnt a market for that anymore ... there would be no .... 'point'.